# How to setup vncserver?

Tags: ubuntu

I bought vps service, ubuntu 16.04 automatically installed (they say),

so I want to install vncserver for remote control while seeing unity GUI,

but can't install vncserver...

google example's terminal shows :/$ or ~$, but why mine is :/#? How to change?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /$ or ~$, but why mine is :/#? How to change?

`:/#` means that you are logged as `root` user in root of your system.

It's shown in your terminal: `root@wsxdr3:/#`. But in case if you're not sure you can always use this command: `whoami`.

That's ok. `:~$`  that you see online means that you are using shell as non root user. `~` is shortcut for your $HOME path which is home folder of user.

If you want to use vnc you need to make sure that your remote machine has GUI installed (that means desktop environment like Gnome, KDE and others)

[Answer on how to determine if machine has GUI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237594/how-to-check-from-terminal-if-any-gui-installed-in-ubuntu)

[Here are instructions how to install vncserver on Ubuntu 16.04](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/tightvnc-server-ubuntu-1604)